# How would I align the center of a background image with the center of a widget?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile

The app is composed of a column which takes up the whole screen and two children. The top child is expanded and the bottom child has an aspect ratio. I am looking for a way to use an image as a background for the whole app but the center of the image has to align with the center of the top child. I am able to make this image asset as big as necessary or however proportioned in order to accommodate the screen and let it get cut off. But, because the bottom child spans the width of the screen and it is sized by an aspect ratio, its height changes depending on the width of the screen, therefore the ratio of heights between the top and bottom widgets are not concrete. Any thoughts on how you would approach this problem?

My initial thought was to somehow get the height of the top widget and use that to position the background image, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that and I'm worried that it doesn't quite make sense with the order of operations of rendering.

Here's my attempt at an [image of the wireframe of app layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H13hj.png)

Currently, without the image, the code looks something like this:

```
Column(children: [
  Expanded(child: Container()),
  AspectRatio(ratio: 4/3, child: Container())
])
```

Comment: would you mind to share a code or image

Comment: @RajNarola added an image of a wireframe of what i want. I hope it's helpful. It's not great haha

Comment: your widget 2 has to specify it's fixed width or height - otherwise it can take different sizes with given aspect ratio

Comment: @pskink it is the intention that widget two changes its size depending on screen size.

Comment: how? It can have sizes like 4x3 8x6 16x12 etc because the upper widget (widget 1) can have also any size

Comment: @pskink I'm confused. What you are describing is exactly the intention. The two widgets will change their sizes depending on screen size. That is what happens and it is what is intended to happen. It is also what makes my question challenging. If one of them had a fixed size, or there was a fixed ratio between them, finding the center of the top widget would not be complex. But that is not the intended design.

Comment: ok, so widget 1 has any fixed width or height? if not there can be infinite combinations of sizes for widget 1 and 2

Comment: for example let the big (red) rect is 100x100 then it can be 4x3 for widget 2 and 4x(100-3-3) for widget 1, or 8x6 for widget 2 and 8x(100-6-6) for widget 1 or .... (I hope you got the idea)